# Site is working but we got 404 not found error in wordpress

Tags: 404-error

I have a wordpress site hosted on AWS. Site is working fine but I'm facing an issue. When the page loads, we get 404 not found error for that link in console first. It is happening on all the pages like home page, posts page, categories page etc. Like whole site is doing this. If anyone have solution, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to refresh your permalinks by going to wp-admin > Settings > Permalink. No need to change any settings or save them, only visiting is creating the `.htaccess` if not already created and add the correct rules if needed.

Let us know.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: That was my htaccess rule. now tell me the solution

Comment: @RaoTalhaZahidKhan I would suggest [editing your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/407867/edit) with additional information. You may also need to know that "Now tell me the solution" is a bit rude; people will be less moved to help if addressed like that.